# Show loading indicator between navigation of pages in a Webview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

I have a url in the Webview like https://www.nytimes.com/  The current code works inital page load but If I type tap anything in the link, the page takes a while to load and there are no loading indicators in the website. Is there any way we can put a page loading indicator in React Native while we click on any link or page loading specially if it is server side rendered like next js?

Here is my ReactNative code.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
// import WelcomeSwiper from '../../components/WelcomeScreen/WelcomeSwiper';

import LoadingIcon from '../../components/Loading/index.js';

const WebView = ({ navigation }) => {


  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>

      <WebView
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
        renderLoading={LoadingIcon}
        source={{ uri: 'https://www.nytimes.com/ ' }}
        startInLoadingState={true}

      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default WebView;
```

Here is my loading component

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Platform, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';


const LoadingIcon = () => {
    return (

        <ActivityIndicator
            color='#009688'
            size='large'
            style={styles.ActivityIndicatorStyle}
        />
    );
}

export default LoadingIcon;


const styles = StyleSheet.create(
    {

        WebViewStyle:
        {
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            flex: 1,
            marginTop: (Platform.OS) === 'ios' ? 20 : 0
        },

        ActivityIndicatorStyle: {
            position: 'absolute',
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center'

        }
    });
```

Comment: Is your code not working or do you want any other solution?

Comment: This code works while the 1st time the page loads but the links in page loading after the page loads is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use `onLoadProgress` to solve this issue.

`renderLoading` function is just called at the initial loading state of webview component. Using renderLoading is not helpful to show activity indicators at any tap on page links or navigating between webview pages.

Checking `onLoadStart` and `onLoadEnd` is useful in android but in iOS `onLoadEnd` is not called in the back navigation gesture which results in endless spinning of activity indicator.

`onLoadProgress` returns a number between 0-1 while webview is in the loading state. You check its progress state and update your activity indicator state.

For more information about `onLoadProgress`: [onLoadProgress](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#onloadprogress)

Here is a working code example for you:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, SafeAreaView, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';

function WebViewTest() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://www.nytimes.com/'}}
        onLoadProgress={({nativeEvent}) => {
                    if (nativeEvent.progress != 1 && isLoading == false ) {
                        setLoading(true)
                    } else if (nativeEvent.progress == 1 ) {
                        setLoading(false)
                    }
                }} 
        />
        {isLoading && (
          <View style={{flex: 10, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
            <ActivityIndicator
              color="#009688"
              size="large"
            //   style={{position: 'absolute', left: 200, top: 300}}
            />
          </View>
        )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default WebViewTest;
```

Answer (score 5):

we can use these two approaches to get the result:

1. You can check if the WebView is loading something or not with the `onLoadProgress` method. This method gives you a number between 0 and 1. If the page is fully loaded it will return number 1, update your state and show the ActivityIndicator according to it:
2. you can use `onLoadStart` and `onLoadEnd` to update your state and show the ActivityIndicator according to it!

for more info check the:  https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#onloadprogress

you can also use your `ActivityIndicator` **wrapped by WebView**, ***do not Forget this method works in ios for android put it outside of WebView**

[image]

and this is a working code sample for you:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, SafeAreaView, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';

function WebViewTest() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://www.nytimes.com/'}}
        onLoadStart={(syntheticEvent) => {
          setLoading(true);
        }}
        onLoadEnd={(syntheticEvent) => {
          setLoading(false);
        }} />
        {isLoading && (
          <View style={{flex: 10, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
            <ActivityIndicator
              color="#009688"
              size="large"
            //   style={{position: 'absolute', left: 200, top: 300}}
            />
          </View>
        )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default WebViewTest;
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I guess the web view cannot have children I'm getting this error  RNCWebViewManager cannot be cast to ViewGroupManager

Comment: in ios as i mentioned you can pass components as children but in Android you should have your component outside of the WebView~~~ , you can also implement it outside for having a cleaner code!

Comment: Can you explain the hack for both IOS and Android

Comment: do you need this?

Comment: Yes but see the page is loaded for the 1st time but during the links inside the page they take time to load

Comment: i edited my answer, use the same code and check the result

Comment: `progress` will return 0-1, but I searched a lot, but I can't find the documentation of `progress`?

Comment: onLoadProgress is the prop you can use for checking the progress @weiyaou

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#onloadprogress
@weiyaou

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. LoadProgress does not seem to be getting called on page clicks within the same source domain